# When should call GC.Collect()?

Tags: wpf, garbage-collection, c++-cli, bitmapsource

I'm using BitmapSource to draw frames as video that get from IP Camera. The below is summary code.

```
while(true)
{
    char* rgbBuffer = GetFrameFromCamera();
    BitmapSource^ bitmapSource = BitmapSource::Create(resX, resY, 96, 96, PixelFormats::Bgr24, nullptr, (IntPtr)rgbBuffer, rgbBufferLength, linesize);
    wpfVideoControl.Draw(bitmapSource); 
    delete []rgbBuffer;
}
```

The problem is, the memory usage that watched from Task Manager is very large. And after along time, when the memory usage about 1300MB, `the application is not responding`.

My application is 32bit, and the resolution of IP Camera is 1280x960, frame per second is 25 and there are 4 cameras. Each bitmap frame is about 3,5 MB. It mean the velocity allocation memory for this case about 3,5*25*4 = 350 MB/second.

So the memory is increased very fast and seem the GC can not cover it. Therefore that caused `"The application is not responding"`.

I have tried to call `GC.Collect()` in each while loop as below code. And the application was worked fine. But this caused the CPU consuming.

```
while(true)
{
    GC::Collect();
    GC::WaitForPendingFinalizers();
    char* rgbBuffer = GetFrameFromCamera();
    BitmapSource^ bitmapSource = BitmapSource::Create(resX, resY, 96, 96, PixelFormats::Bgr24, nullptr, (IntPtr)rgbBuffer, rgbBufferLength, linesize);
    wpfVideoControl.Draw(bitmapSource); 
    delete []rgbBuffer;
}
```

To avoid the CPU consuming, I have tried to call `GC.Collect()` after 1s by the timer thread below

```
void TimerThread()
{
    while(true)
    {
        GC::Collect();
        GC::WaitForPendingFinalizers();     
        Sleep(1000);
    }
}
```

This way was solved the CPU consuming issue. But the problem very large memory usage still exist.

Someone can show me the best way to solve my problem.

Comment: Is this meant to be C or C++?

Comment: Look into the usage of GC.AddMemoryPressure() and GC.RemoveMemoryPressure(), that will make Gc more "aggressive".

Comment: @DavidPilkington: It is Managed C++